# Why ActivePython freezes after I use the turtle module?

Tags: python, windows, tk-toolkit, turtle-graphics, activepython

I've installed ActivePython 3.1 and ran IDLE with `-n` parameter as required by the turtle module in documentation. However when I try to use it with call such as `turtle.postion()`, new windows is opened (with Tk icon), which freezes and shows nothing.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The immediate cause of the freeze is that the Tk event loop is not being serviced. Without that, Tk windows *do not* display or update correctly (all GUI toolkits are event based, but Tk is particularly so). Unfortunately, I don't know Python's Tk binding or IDLE nearly well enough to be able to say what that is caused by.

Answer (score 0):

Partially resolved by not running it in IDLE, I execute it as a python script and wait for input to see what is drawn.